# jQuery - create div on div with content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have div #one with content and I want (but I don't know how) create (via jQuery) second div on div #one with div #one content, like:

```
<div id="one">
  <p>Content content</p>
</div>

<div id="one">
  <div id="second" style="width: xxxpx; ...">
    <p>Content content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll get answers that tell you how to do *exactly* what you've asked for - I could do that now - but is that good enough?  Is this something that you're going to want to extend further?

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/rKhg6/

Comment: I'm voting to re-open since I can't see *any* difficulty in understanding what was asked in this question. The quality of the question is relatively poor, I agree, but it is in no way 'unclear.'

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#one').wrapInner('<div id="second"></div>');
```

This basically selects the element(s) (in this case the `#one` element), and wraps the entirety of its child-nodes with the HTML string passed in the `wrapInner()` method.

Obviously, I suppose, this method comes into its own when performing the same content-change to a larger number of elements than just one, but even in the case of 'just one' it can still be a time-saver.

References:

- [`wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/).

Comment: Oh that is nice. Typo, but nice: $('#one').wrapInner('<div id="second"></div>');

Comment: Chris, thanks for the catch; and @j08691, thanks for the edit! =)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('p').wrap('<div id="second"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

Code:

```
$('#one').contents().wrap('<div id="second" style="width: xxxpx; ..."></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the jQuery.wrap function http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

```
$('#one p').wrap('<div id="second" style="width: xxxpx; ...">');
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/x5TAp/

```
$('#one').contents().wrapAll('<div id="second"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
// get html for first div
var divOneHtml = $("#one").html();
// create inner div
var div2 = document.createElement("div");
// set id
div2.id="second";
// set css
div2.style = "<style>";
// set content of inner div to original content of outer div
$(div2).html(divOneHtml);
// append second div to original div
$("#one").append(div2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work...

```
var currentContent = $('#one').html();
var secondDiv = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'second').html(currentContent);
$('#one').html(secondDiv);
```

PS: heh, guess I was too late and not the optimal answer after all

:p

EDIT -> added jsfiddle url: http://jsfiddle.net/RqvLU/